# capistrano3 triggers initializers on deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, capistrano3

Deploying in remote server with cap3 triggering initializers, I want to trigger the initializers only on application startup and not on anything else.

I have added an config/initializers/xxx.rb file.

When I am running cap staging deploy, the  task itself triggers initializers file. I want to trigger the initializers only on application startup. How to do that?